# Did I solve these limits right?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have some limits that I tried solving:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}(4x^5+2x^3-1)=4(2)^5+2(2)^3-1=143$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(\frac{5x}{x-1})=\frac{5}{0}=does~not~exist$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow(-3)}(\frac{x^2-5x-24}{4x+12})=\frac{(x+3)(x-8)}{4(x+3)}=\frac{x-8}{4}=-\frac{11}{4}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow4}(\frac{x^2-16}{x-4})=\frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{x-4}=x+4=8$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x})=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}*\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow27}(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-3}{x-27})=\lim_{u\rightarrow3}\frac{u-3}{u^3-27}=\frac{u-3}{(u-3)(u^2+3u+9)}=\frac{1}{u^2+3u+9)}=\frac{1}{27}$

Did I do everything right? Was there any mistakes in my approach?

Comment: I don't think there is any, but when you are cancelling the same thing from the numerator and denominator, then you should mention that as $x \rightarrow a$, $x \neq a$.

Comment: These look good!

Comment: So you're saying that in the 4th one, where I rationalize and factor it to be x+4, I shouldn't substitute x with 4 to get 8? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry, the first limit was calculated improperly, I skipped that one in my since you did it right but your arithmetic was wrong :P

Comment: Ah, my bad. The calculation isn't wrong, I'd just accidentally written $2x^2$ when it should have been $2x^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to these is spot on, in all cases. You've done very well! Nice work!

Note, that when canceling common factors in the numerator and denominator, for example, say, the factor $(x-a)$ in a limit for which $x \to a$, you should specify $x \neq a$.

Comment: Ah, actually, it's not a miscalculation, I just wrote the wrong equation. It's supposed to be $2x^3$ not $2x^2$. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Updated my post accordingly!

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify a bit on the note there? I've just started calculus, and so far the course material I'm reading hasn't mentioned anything about specifying that $x\ne a$ when you factor and cancel out common factors in the numerator and denominator. What does it mean to specify that $x\ne a$ in this case? What difference does it make? And why is it necessary?

Comment: Substitution is fine, once you've canceled the common factors. Just remember that technically, with a limit, e.g., as $x \to a$, we aren't simply calculating $f(a)$. We are calculating the limit of a function as $x \to a$. It turns out that substitution works in most cases, but it's always good, when canceling terms, to note that $x \neq a$. (E.g., when the original denominator is zero at $f(a)$.) That *doesn't mean* that after canceling such a term, that you can't proceed as you did.

Comment: So, for example, for your third limit, my suggestion is that you write: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow(-3)}(\frac{x^2-5x-24}{4x+12})=\lim_{x \to (-3)} \frac{(x+3)(x-8)}{4(x+3)}=\lim_{x \to -3} \frac{x-8}{4}=-\frac{11}{4}, \;x\neq -3$$ that's all. $x$, here, is approaching $(-3)$, it doesn't need to *be* (-3).

Comment: Ah, right, like that. I understand. It's sort of a way of saying that at $x=-3$, the actual y-value could be something entirely else. I only found the value we get as $x$ *approaches* $-3$, not when it **is** $-3$.